No se ejecutan las tareas en cola Celery - Redis
Tengo el siguiente celery_app.py:
from celery import Celery

celery = Celery('celery_app')

celery.conf.update(
    broker_url='redis://localhost:6379/0',
    result_backend='redis://localhost:6379/0',
    task_default_queue='test-dear',
    imports = (
        'simple_celery_app.tasks',
    ),
)

Las siguientes tareas:
import time
from simple_celery_app.celery_app import celery

@celery.task
def add(x: int, y: int) -> int:
    time.sleep(5)
    return x + y

@celery.task
def mul(x: int, y: int) -> int:
    time.sleep(5)
    return x * y

Tengo a Redis corriendo con Docker de la sieguiente manera
version: '3.9'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:7.0-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 6379:6379

Creo el woker de la siguiente manera:
celery -A simple_celery_app.celery_app worker --loglevel INFO --logfile=celery.log

En otra terminal ejecuto
pipenv run python

y alli importo los metodos de tasks.py
y ejecuto
s = add.delay(10,22)

los log de celery me indica lo siguiente
[2024-05-09 11:24:51,107: INFO/MainProcess] Task simple_celery_app.tasks.add[5e597f66-74a8-40d5-a905-27b3b00430c6] received
[2024-05-09 11:24:51,861: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-16] child process 2696 calling self.run()
[2024-05-09 11:24:51,866: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-15] child process 7456 calling self.run()
[2024-05-09 11:24:51,896: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-14] child process 1228 calling self.run()

Pêro pasado los 5 segundos nunca me devuelve una respusta.
Que puede estar pasando que el worker no agarra la tarea?
Me sucede tambien que Redis almacena a veces si y a veces no, de momento con la instacia actual tengo 5 encoladas, y no se ejecutan

Lo solucione agregando en el comando de celery: --pool=solo

Si usas Windows, el problema puede ser el método prefork, ya que depende de fork, una función de sistemas UNIX que no es compatible con Windows. Esto puede impedir que Celery procese las tareas correctamente.
Lo solucioné cambiando a threads, que funciona bien en Windows. Puedes probar con este comando:
celery -A <tu_aplicacion> worker --loglevel=info --pool=threads

